# How can i fix this problem with file-loader in webpack (for img loader)?

Tags: webpack

When I did this before, it was working without problems. But now the image is not recognized in the html file in the dist.

1. https://ibb.co/wLd0Pxd
2. https://ibb.co/HCj26Hq
3. https://ibb.co/GFN59qY

Comment: Hi & welcome to stackoverflow. Please read the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and extend your question accordingly.

Comment: Please add the picture directly rather than paste a link.